# Possible to concatenate a list with setdefault in Python?

Tags: python

Is there something similar to this:

```
some_dict = {}
some_dict.setdefault('list_key', []).append('some_item')
```

But for concatenating a list?

```
some_dict.setdefault('list_key', []).concat([item1, item2])
```

Comment: Are you looking for this - `some_dict.setdefault('list_key', []).extend(['item1', 'item2'])`

Comment: ah sorry all i found googling was `+=` to concatenate lists, but that is exactly what' i'm looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dictionary value is a list. If you want to concatenate the list with another, you have to use `extend()`

```
some_dict.setdefault('list_key', []).extend([item1, item2])


a_list.append(element)  # adds an element to the end of a_list
a_list.extend(another_list)  # concatenates a_list with another_list.
```

Answer (score 2):

You want the `.extend()` method of lists. This has nothing to do with `.setdefault()`. More details are available in the [list documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).